Converting decimal values in SQL
The available data type conversions for T-SQL are shown in the grid at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16. There's a note at the bottom of this for conversions between decimal/numeric types:

Requires explicit CAST to prevent the loss of precision or scale that might occur in an implicit conversion

Can anyone explain how an explicit conversion helps in this situation?
If I have something like:
declare @d1 numeric(5,2) = 123.45
declare @d2 numeric(10,4) = 123.456

-- Implicit conversion
set @d1 = @d2
select @d1, @d2

-- Explicit conversion
set @d1 = cast(@d2 as numeric(5,2))
select @d1, @d2

I get the same results with both the implicit and explicit conversions. The wording in the docs seems to imply that by using the explicit conversion I could somehow not lose the scale of the updated value. Surely if the target type of the conversion is the same then it shouldn't make a difference if the conversion is being done implicitly or explicitly, so what nuance am I missing that this note is alluding to?

Try CONVERT(decimal,12345.67890). Does it return what you expect? I suspect the answer is no.

Yes it does - the default scale is 0, so the result is 12346. The result is the same if you use either implicit or explicit conversion:
select CONVERT(decimal,12345.67890); declare @d decimal; set @d =12345.67890; select @d; 
Both produce 12346, so why this note in the docs?

But you lost precision; that's the point...

Indeed, but the note suggests that using an explicit cast would somehow prevent that loss, and I can't see how that can happen.

Where is the note?

You need SET ARITHABORT ON btw. If you don't, then it'll silently lose-precision. (Microsoft recommends always setting ARITHABORT ON, but client-software connections might have different defaults).

Note that implicit conversions are not limited to assignments.  Often they occur in the middle of complex arithmetic operations and function parameter conversions.  In many of these cases you would need explicit conversions to control the precision level.

@Luuk - it is at the bottom of the grid image on the linked documentation page, unfortunately it's not in the actual text itself.

@RBarryYoung Thanks, so as I understand it any decimal type conversion can be done either implicitly or explicitly, but this is recommending a best practise to avoid getting unexpected results in these sorts of calculations?

@MarkMpn  I've been retired for 5 years now, but I THINK so.  I definitely remember cases of doing arithmetic with numeric/decimal values where precision got lost somewhere in the middle and the fix was to use explicit CASTing everywhere.

A explicit cast avoids losing precision because you can specify the precision you want instead of having to take the default. Said another way the precision is specifically chosen by you, so you aren't losing anything, rather you are getting whatever you asked for.
